# How to enter number in this input with the developer tool?

Tags: javascript

When clicked `input-currency` it switches to focus `input-currency input-currency_focus`

I Tried: getElementsByClassName; text; inerhtml; value; write;

Which command can I use?

````
<div class="sum 
            field-wrapper  js_tu_deal_sum ">
<div class="deal-form-select-block">
<button type="button" class="deal-form-pick-button  deal-form-select-block__btn" data-test="deal-select-amount-down" data-tracking="" data-product="" data-action=""><span class="deal-form-pick-button__svg-wrapper">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="deal-form-pick-button__svg"><path d="M8.5 12h7a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1h-7a.5.5 0 1 0 0 1z"></path></svg></span></button>
<div class="deal-form-select-block__input">

<div class="input-currency  ">
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="input-currency__input" data-test="deal-amount-input" maxlength="9" 
value="2.5">
<div class="input-currency__values">
<span class="input-currency__value">2.5</span>&nbsp;

<span class="input-currency__sign psign">a</span></div></div></div>
<button type="button" class="deal-form-pick-button  deal-form-select-block__btn" data-test="deal-select-amount-up" data-tracking="" data-product="" data-action=""><span class="deal-form-pick-button__svg-wrapper"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="deal-form-pick-button__svg"><path d="M11 12v3.5a.5.5 0 1 0 1 0V12h3.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1H12V7.5a.5.5 0 1 0-1 0V11H7.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0 1H11z"></path></svg></span></button></div></div>```
````

Comment: What exactly did you try? None of what you've written above is a valid command

Comment: Tried `document.getElementsByClassName('input-currency__input')[0].value = "VALUE"`
 `document.getElementsByClassName('input-currency__input')[0].text = "TExT"`
 `document.getElementsByClassName('input-currency__input')[0].write= "TExT"`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input-currency__input')[0].value = "VALUE"
```

Comment: so it types but returns the old value which is 2.5

Comment: perhaps it uses the span inner html as the value? weird, you can give this a try: document.getElementsByClassName('input-currency__value')[0].innerHTML = "VALUE"